# Bitwise XOR uudecode string in Perl

Tags: perl, encoding, xor, uuencode

I have the following strings at left with encoded values at right:

```
123456789012                ,\#8%-SM+"Q$[2C4?_\n
1234567890123               -\#8%-SM+"Q$[2C4?_SP  \n
12345678901234              .\#8%-SM+"Q$[2C4?_S], \n
123456789012345             /\#8%-SM+"Q$[2C4?_S],,\n
1234567890123456            0\#8%-SM+"Q$[2C4?_S],,*   \n
12345678901234567           1\#8%-SM+"Q$[2C4?_S],,**D \n
123456789012345678          2\#8%-SM+"Q$[2C4?_S],,**GA\n
1234567890123456789         3\#8%-SM+"Q$[2C4?_S],,**GA]P  \n
12345678901234567890        4\#8%-SM+"Q$[2C4?_S],,**GA]]0 \n
123456789012345678901       5\#8%-SM+"Q$[2C4?_S],,**GA]]3^\n
1234567890123456789012      6\#8%-SM+"Q$[2C4?_S],,**GA]]3^_   \n
12345678901234567890123     7\#8%-SM+"Q$[2C4?_S],,**GA]]3^_(< \n
123456789012345678901234    8\#8%-SM+"Q$[2C4?_S],,**GA]]3^_(>'\n
```

I tried to replicate the decoding procedure (uudecode -> XOR with key) like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$key = pack("H*","3cb37efae7f4f376ebbd76cdfc");

print "Enter string to decode: ";
$str=<STDIN>;chomp $str; $str =~s/\\(.)/$1/g;
$dec = decode($str);
print "Decoded string value: $dec\n";

sub decode{ #Sub to decode
    my ($sqlstr) = @_;
    $cipher = unpack("u", $sqlstr);
    $plain = $cipher^$key;
    return substr($plain, 0, length($cipher));
}
```

All works well until I get to a string made of 13 characters:

```
# perl d.pl
Enter string to decode: -\#8%-SM+"Q$[2C4?_SP  \n
Decoded string value: 1234567890123

# perl d.pl
Enter string to decode: .\#8%-SM+"Q$[2C4?_S], \n
Decoded string value: 1234567890123Ó
```

Any idea on how can I decode all the encoded datas? Thanks!

Ok, figured it out myself bruteforcing the key in HEX. This key `3cb37efae7f4f376ebbd76cdfce7391e9ed9cee4cfceb4b3` decodes all my encrypted data.

SOLUTION, cleaner code thanks to ikegami:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

sub deliteral {
   my ($s) = @_;
   $s =~ s/\\n/\n/g;
   die "Unrecognised escape \\$1\n"
      if $s =~ /(?<!\\)(?:\\{2})*\\([a-zA-Z0-9])/;
   $s =~ s/\\(.)/$1/sg;
   return $s;
}

sub uudecode {
   return unpack 'u', $_[0];
}

sub decode {
   my ($key, $cipher) = @_;
   return substr($cipher^$key, 0, length($cipher));
}

my $key = pack('H*', '3cb37efae7f4f376ebbd76cdfce7391e9ed9cee4cfceb4b3');

print "Enter string to decode: ";
chomp( my $coded = <STDIN> );

my $cipher = uudecode(deliteral($coded));
my $plain = decode($key, $cipher);
print("Plain text: $plain\n");
```

Output:

```
$ perl deXOR.pl
Enter string to decode: ,\#8%-SM+"Q$[2C4?_\n
Plain text: 123456789012
$ perl deXOR.pl
Enter string to decode: 8\#8%-SM+"Q$[2C4?_S],,**GA]]3^_(>'\n
Plain text: 123456789012345678901234
```

Comment: How are the data encoded?

Comment: Some Java, I encoded it manually from admin panel.

Comment: Is the encoding algorithm documented? Can you view its source?

Comment: Here is the java and an old discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10085074/java-to-perl-port-xor-encryptor-class/10085294

Comment: Mixed up the scripts. Anyway I'm bruteforcing HEX, I can already decode 17 characters long string with `3cb37efae7f4f376ebbd76cdfce7391e9e` key.

Comment: @ikegami, by the way, your script fails at this string `*4\\L'GM?,EQ?9B0  \n` any idea?

Comment: Yes, this works: `$s =~ /(?<!\\)(?:\\{2})*\\([a-zA-Z0-9])/`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the solution to my question. I bruteforced the key HEX byte by byte.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

sub deliteral {
   my ($s) = @_;
   $s =~ s/\\n/\n/g;
   die "Unrecognised escape \\$1\n"
      if $s =~ /(?<!\\)(?:\\{2})*\\([a-zA-Z0-9])/;
   $s =~ s/\\(.)/$1/sg;
   return $s;
}

sub uudecode {
   return unpack 'u', $_[0];
}

sub decode {
   my ($key, $cipher) = @_;
   return substr($cipher^$key, 0, length($cipher));
}

my $key = pack('H*', '3cb37efae7f4f376ebbd76cdfce7391e9ed9cee4cfceb4b3');

print "Enter string to decode: ";
chomp( my $coded = <STDIN> );

my $cipher = uudecode(deliteral($coded));
my $plain = decode($key, $cipher);
print("Plain text: $plain\n");
```

Comment: Why doesn't provide an answer? I answered myself at the bottom, should I write here?

Comment: At the bottom of what? If you've solved your question, post it as an answer, and accept it.

Comment: Do me a favor and check if works for plain text `abcdefghijklm`

Comment: @ikegami, yes it does, `-7\=$\=GH*2E\!Z"UQVAD0  \n` is encrypted value of `abcdefghijklm` and that works. Anyway, your script fails at "Unrecognised escape" in examples like `*4\\L'GM?,EQ?9B0  \n` or `,6]\\3B8Z9@QJ.Q4_T\n` but works decoding anyway if I remove the checking with `$s =~ /\\[a-zA-Z0-9]/` because `\\[a-zA-Z0-9]` doesn't escape `alnum` but escapes itself.

Comment: Yes, `$s =~ /(?<!\\)(?:\\{2})*\\([a-zA-Z0-9])/` is sanitizing better the input.

Comment: Seems people here that doesn't like to help just vote for "unuseful"...really guys??